# What is a nonce-respecting adversary?

Tags: terminology, nonce

The NORX8 paper says

> It is assumed that adversaries are nonce-respecting.

What is a nonce-respecting adversary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We call an adversary *A nonce-respecting* if it never repeats a nonce

Source: [Nonce-Based Symmetric Encryption](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/nonce.pdf)

This is defined in the context of the [IND-CPA game](https://crypto.graphics/CPA/).