# Can Trivium be used as a PRF?

Tags: stream-cipher, pseudo-random-function

The Trivium encryption algorithm has two inputs, key and IV, both of which are 80 bits long. Let's call it Trivium(key, IV) → keystream. My question is whether doing Trivium(key, input) and taking the first 80 bit of keystream would result in a secure PRF.

I have found [another way](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2278/71665) to create a PRF from a stream cipher, but that seems to be for stream ciphers that do not have an IV input, so such a complex construction might not be needed for one that does. Based on reading the [Trivium algorithm description paper](https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/p3ciphers/trivium/trivium_p3.pdf) and the [Trivium design paper](https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/papersdir/2006/021.pdf) I feel like my construction should be secure but I have no idea how to go around proving it.

This question was spurred by wondering whether I could implement authenticated encryption using only Trivium as a primitive. If I could turn it into a PRF, as far as I understand I could construct something similar to CBC-MAC from it. (Of course this doesn't make much sense to because rekeying the cipher, which you'd need to do for every 8 bytes, is quite slow.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the standard security proof for CPA security of nonce-based stream ciphers _does_ assume the stream cipher to behave like a PRF.

Comment: With the limited description above, wouldn't your input data be limited to 80 bits / 10 bytes?

Comment: Yes. My understanding was that a PRF is usually defined to map from a fixed-size input to a fixed-size output. Is that not correct?

Comment: @nortti: PRFs can have either fixed- or variable-size input domains. Block ciphers are the most common example of fixed-size input PRFs. HMAC is the most common example of a variable input size PRF, but see also CMAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To attempt such a proof you need a definition of what security properties an IV-based stream cipher is supposed to provide.  For example, like this (very informally):

- A nonce-based cipher is secure if and only if its encryptions are indistinguishable from random bitstrings of the same length to a [nonce-respecting adversary](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46755/what-is-a-nonce-respecting-adversary) that's allowed to carry out a chosen-plaintext attack.

The "nonce-respecting" bit is important, because one of the key assumptions in a PRF is that it's supposed to be secure against adversarially-chosen inputs, and the inclusion of "nonce-respecting" in such a definition is to give the adversary as much control over nonces as we can get away with.  (Note not all ciphers meet this standard—e.g., CBC-mode encryption doesn't, because it requires random nonces. Evaluating whether Trivium meets this standard is a whole 'nother topic.)

So if encrypting message $p$ with key $k$ and nonce $n$ is notated as $Enc^n_k(p)$,
then your proposed PRF construction would be:

$$
PRF_k(m) = Enc^m_k(0^{80})
$$

...where $0^{80}$ is the 80-bit all-zero string.  And what you want to prove is that, given a secret, random choice of $k$, if an attacker who can choose messages $m$ could distinguish your PRF apart from a random function, then they could break the underlying nonce-based cipher.

In this case, that follows by observing that if there was such a chosen-message attack they could mount against the PRF, it would imply the existence a corresponding attack on the cipher by querying for the encryption of the same plaintext $0^{80}$ repeatedly but with different, adversarially-controlled nonces.

Comment: Wouldn't using the message as a nonce input restrict the message size for most stream ciphers?