# Why Block Ciphers

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher, stream-cipher, chacha

I​ fail to understand what block ciphers can do that stream ciphers cannot.
Also aren't they construct able from one another.
prg(stream cipher) -> prf -> prp(block cipher)
Any practical example would be very helpful

Comment: Reusing gamma (or key, which gamma is derived from) in stream ciphers lead to their insecurity. That's why you cannot reuse key-nonce pair for some block cipher modes of operations, that turn block ciphers into stream ones. In contrast block ciphers (with proper use of modes of operations) are CPA-secure (key can be used several times)

Comment: I'm not sure that it is that practical to go from PRG-> PRF. There is an answer on how to do that [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/74881/1172). On the other hand, you can create a hash, MAC (PRF) or stream cipher (PRG) and even an authenticated mode (OCB) rather easily from a block cipher (or, of course, from a sponge construction :) ) Beware that any logical reasoning here may not answer your actual question: **why**. Block ciphers are old constructs, they were created because somebody designed them I suppose.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I can see that one of the tags is "chacha" and the existence of chcha20+poly1305  is a reason that we do not need PRP block-ciphers to achieve most of our desired security properties.

Comment: Can we confidently say that ChaCha itself doesn't have block cipher properties though?

Comment: @Habib  sousemanuk and other [estream ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESTREAM)  i think are also similar to salsa(chaha)  in that respect, and i dont know but maybe there are more of em.

Comment: @Maarten aes was adopted in 2001 and salsa was also pre 2004, looking at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) they seems to be of roughly same age, it may not be efficient for all prg->prf construction but for many it is, same can be said for all prp-prg construction in efficieny, also ciphers like salasa(chaha) are made directly form prf (again from wiki page).......... chacha does share properties of block cipher and even sosemanuk was inspired by a block cipher, but still they are classified as stream ciphers

Comment: @GeorgyFirsov i dont know what you mean by gamma, do u mean naunce, but clearly chaha is considered a substitute for aes, with mac (poly1305 or (blake)) etc it can be made even cca secure, i guess (iam kindda new to this stuff), with better perfomence on non hardware support

Comment: @xzijoq gamma in stream ciphers is a pseudorandom sequence that is combined with plain text to produce ciphertext. It is generated from a key using PRNG. Consider the following stream cipher: $c = \gamma \oplus m$, where $m$ is a plaintext unit (bit, or byte, or smth. else), $c$ $-$ corresponding ciphertext unit and $\gamma$ is a pseudorandom sequence (gamma). When turn block cipher into stream one (CTR, OFB, CFB, etc. modes) gamma is generated from key and nonce using a block cipher

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Interestingly, I recently asked one my of friends this very question and she told me maybe the reason is designing and analysing the security of block-ciphers is easier than stream-ciphers. And, chcha20 is an example of stream-ciphers which try to mimick block-ciphers wiuthout losing the performance that a stream-cipher has. (Probably analysing block-ciphers is easier because we have developed more tools and methods for them)